# can you change a grade in google classroom using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

How can you use the API to set grades?
I have spent a day researching Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.patch.  It does not seem to work.
I have used the following code.  It creates error @ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not permitted to make this request. 
all other functions seem to work.  From what I can find patch only will work on an assignment created by the console.  So if I understand correctly the API ...patch can only set or change grades if the user is a teacher that created the assignment using the API as well.  That seems ridiculously limited.

```
function whatIsIn(){
  var studentSubmission ={ "assignedGrade" : 80} 
  var course = 8684648155;
  var courseWork = 9148083677; 
  var optionalArgs = {
    courseStates: 'ACTIVE',
    pageSize: 10

  };
  var upDate = {
    updateMask : 'assignedGrade'
  };
  Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.patch(studentSubmission, course, courseWork, 'CgwI85SByhoQ3duSiiI',upDate); 

}
```

So the choices seem to be:  This is wrong; There is no way, or there is a method I do not know.

If there is no way that seems rather limiting.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions), you will see that there are two kinds of grade `draftGrade` and `assignedGrade`. These two grades are optional and must be non-negative integers at the same time, decimal values are allowed. Unfortunately, these two field are only modifiable by a course teacher.

For more information, check this [Classroom Help](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6020294?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

I've been running tests and, indeed, it is only possible to change grades that have been created through the API.
In this case, your code olny need one thin

you wrote:
 var upDate = {
    updateMask : 'assignedGrade'
};

and the correct option is
 var upDate = {
    'updateMask' : 'assignedGrade'
};